# Why does Axl Rose wear Jesus Christ tshirts?

Tags: rock, guns-n-roses

Does anyone of you know why Axl Rose wears that famous Jesus Christ tshirt with "KILL YOUR IDOLS" sign on the bottom?

Comment: Because it's laundry day.